# Change Raphael cursor when not over object - just paper

Tags: raphael

In Raphael, I'd like to set the cursor shape when it is not over an element (but is over the Raphael paper.  I still want it to change when hovering over certain elements as well.

I want the cursor shape over the paper to depend on a JS condition so it can't just be a simple CSS hover event over the canvas.

Comment: One way is to add or remove a CSS class to the paper element and use the hover event to set the cursor shape based on that class.